# How can I display whatever I need from website?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have developed some company website in that i had careers option.now using text view i am displaying job openings,but when they update in website app also should get update and if they want to post in app only means how i update or post job opening after placing in google play store. please explain with code.

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wv);

webView.loadUrl("http://www.emergtechinc.com/Careers/careers-cjo.aspx");
```

I used webview and displayed the currenopenings page. Is it right but I got whole website page. How can I display whatever I need from website?

Comment: Create a page with the contents that you want to display and load that page in the web view. But make sure that the list of openings for both the pages (computer and mobile) is fetched from same source.

Comment: Stop shouting for one thing...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load specific data only, I would suggest an API on the backend of your website.  Create a specific Activity in you app that queries the API, which would return data for job postings, and display it in any manner you would like.

If you want users to post to the site from the application, you will also need an API to handle the post.

@Prerak's answer will work as well and be less code than the method I am suggesting.

Comment: First you would need to create an API endpoint for your website that returns a [json response](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=asp.net+web+service+return+json+example).  Next, you need to call the API from your app, [parse the response, and display it](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Android+Decode+Json+and+Display&tbm=vid).

Comment: give me sample code i am not understanding thses videos.